# How to update a label every time minute changes?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, time

So I've been searching Stackoverflow for a good solution on how to update label if the time change, but so far the results have been unsatisfactory. Most use a timer, and that's not what I want.

What I want is if the status bar time is `8:52 PM` and if some arbitrary bus leaves at `9:00 PM` then I want the label to show `8 min`. Then, if the time changes to `8:53 PM` I want the label to show `7 min`.

I'd prefer some sort of notification or delegation method rather than setting a timer.

If anyone has any suggestions on what I should do (or any 3rd party libraries that could notify if the time changes) that would be great!

Comment: Just create a custom label subclassing UILabel and add the timer to it instead of using it at the view controller

Answer (score 1):

You only have limited choices. If your app is not running in the foreground, you're limited to local notifications, which display an alert to the user. Using those once a minute would be awful for the user.

When your app comes to the foreground you can start a timer that is timed to fire every minute on the minute and use that to update a label in your app:

```
  weak var timer: Timer?
  func startTimer() {
    timer?.invalidate()
    let interval = Double(Date().timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate)
    let delay = 60  - fmod(interval, 60.0)
    message.text = "Delay = \(delay)"

    //Create a "one-off" timer that fires on the next even minute
    let _ = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: delay, repeats: false ) { timer in
      self.message.text = "\(Date())"
      self.timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 60.0,
                                        repeats: true ) { timer in
                                          //Put your repeating code here.
                                          self.message.text = "\(Date())"
      }
    }
  }
```